# Transfering elements of 2D array into cell array

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to instantly transfer elements of an `n x n` numerical array into an `n x n` cell array and vice versa so that each cell in the cell array has element's row, column, and value? E.g.,

```
Input:

A=[8    7     8     4     5;
  7     0     7     4     4;
  4     3     3     8     6;
  7     0    10     8     7;
  2     1     0     2     8;];

B=cell(5,5);

Output:

B{1}=[1 1 8];
B{2}=[2 1 7];
B{3}=[3 1 4];
B{4}=[4 1 7];
B{5}=[5 1 2];
B{6}=[1 2 7];
and so on...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "instantly"? Like not doing any work? What have you done to solve it?

Comment: Also, is A always a square matrix?

Comment: By instantly I mean without using a for loop because it'll be too slow for large matrices. A and B are always square matrices.

Comment: How have you written `B`? I don't see `[1 1 8]` anywhere in `A`.

Comment: In the Matlab documentation and Google engine I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar It is first row, first column, value 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
[row, col] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1));
B=arrayfun(@(x,y,z) [x y z], row(:), col(:), A(:), 'uni', 0);
```

Interesting point is that if you use

```
B=arrayfun(@(x,y,z) [x y z], row, col, A, 'uni', 0);
```

you get cell array `B` with the same size as `A` where each element is in its corresponding element in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
dim=length(A); %//square matrix
cols = repmat(1:dim,dim,1);
rows = cols';
B=reshape(num2cell([rows(:) cols(:) A(:)],2),dim,dim);
```

You could wrap this piece of code in a function if you are going to use it often, to "instantly" transfer the elements of the matrix to the cell array.